# How to get toolbar button indexes for AutoIt automation

Tags: automation, controls, toolbar, autoit

I am trying to automate a third-party program to industrialize a user process at work.  Basically, we're looking for a one-touch solution to set a given test's required settings in Racelogic's VBOXTools.  The problem is that in one of the windows required to find the settings files, I must pass a command to select a toolbar option.  However, not WinID, AutoIt's AU3Info, or WindowDetective will give me an index for the button in question.  Is it possible to pass this command to the program without using the Mouseclick function? If so, how?

Comment: What is the class name for the toolbar?

Comment: The class name is "TTBToolbar"

Comment: Have you tried spy++?

Comment: I haven't yet because I'm trying to do this on my work computer, which doesn't have Visual Studio.  I'm going to download a trial of VS2010 Professional to see if Spy++ will do better than the freeware versions I've tried. For reference, this is on a WinXP machine so a newer version Visual Studio is out of the question.

Comment: To follow up, Spy++ didn't help me to get any farther.  All of the aforementioned tools will recognize the window that the buttons are in, but won't give me any indication of the actual buttons.

Comment: Have you considered [Automa](http://www.getautoma.com)? Maybe it will be able to automate this program - take a look at the _get_name_under_mouse()_ function. If it returns a non-empty strings when you hover over the buttons, then [Automa](http://www.getautoma.com) will be able to find & click them. If not, you can still use the image-based automation approach (take a screenshot of each button and use the images, i.e. _click(Image("button1.png")_).

Answer (score 1):

TTBToolbar is a custom control ([link](http://www.jrsoftware.org/tb2k.php)), so it's likely it won't use the standard system of button ids.

The best way to go would be to look at the position of the button, relative to the toolbar, and ControlClick() the toolbar at that position. I assume the button position does not change.

Comment: The reason to avoid ControlClick() with absolute position in this case is because the program will open windows in different positions , seemingly based on the last location of the window.  Since the automator is going to be installed on several computers used by different people, it's unlikely the automator will be effective 100% of the time by using ControlClick().  However, I could probably set the window location and then the positional reference should work each time.

Comment: @KennyBrown, ControlClick uses relative coords, so window position doesn't matter. The only time it would break is if the button on the toolbar changes it's position relative to the parent.